# unable to find a qt build ... qmake.exe could not be found

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2013

I'm using VS 2013 and Qt 5.8.1 . I've installed add-in and now I get the error "unable to find a qt build" (when trying to build a qt application project). I already tried qt->options->add ; but then again , I get the error "qmake.exe could not be found" (I can see the qmake.exe in bin folder but windows can not find that) 
How can I solve this ?

Comment: You could try adding the qmake path to the system environment variables.

Comment: @eyllanesc I already tried that .... Anyways , I ignored this problem and started coding with Qt creator

Answer (score 2):

In this question you did not mention which path you were putting while configuring QT options. Anyway, just for future needing, I share the correct solution I used to solve this problem.

- Download and install QT package on your machine
  (download available [here](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.2/5.2.0/qt-windows-opensource-5.2.0-msvc2010-x86-offline.exe.mirrorlist))
- Once QT is installed, go to QT VS Tool menu in VS
  Click on QT Options
- On the opened window click Add and insert a Name (e.g. QT5_2) and the following path:
  C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\5.2.0\msvc2010